# Hide link text in master page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have created a simple login page using .net template connected to local SQL DB. i need to hide log off link text in master page i have done this using html tag   but once user login need to enable "logoff" text and hide Sign in text in code behind page. kindly help me
master page

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
 <AnonymousTemplate>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="Default.aspx" Visible ="false">Log out</a>
    </li> 
  </ul>  
 </AnonymousTemplate>
```

Comment: Check the session, if there is value in session change Visible to true.

Comment: You should look into the `LoginStatus` Control.

Answer (score 0):

add this class and Id to link:

```
<a runat="server" id="logoutId" class="hidden-link" href="Default.aspx">Log out</a>
```

add this to your css:

```
a.hidden-link {
    display: none;
}
```

You can use javascript to show/hide links, by adding/removing hidden-link class:

```
// hide
document.getElementById("logoutId").classList.add("hidden-link");

// show
document.getElementById("logoutId").classList.remove("hidden-link");
```

Or you can:

```
<a runat="server" id="logoutId" style="display: none;" href="Default.aspx">Log out</a>
```

and then use juavascript to show/hide

```
// show
document.getElementById("logoutId").style.display = 'block';

// hide 
document.getElementById("logoutId").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: in which CSS Page i need to add code in "master.css" or  "Active function page" more over i am not getting .hidden-link  in CS page.  protected void                                                                 
       Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: it is good practice to put your css in a seperate file and reference them from html: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/styles.css">, have a look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp. Or just use the second method and you won't need a separate css, but you still need javascript to show/hide the link.